# Efficiently call remote processes

Tags: tramp, process, remote

I would like to be able to manage external processes from Emacs, in a way that is:

- **(a)** safe w.r.t. arguments escaping for the shell,
- **(b)** efficient both for local and remote processes (using TRAMP w/ ssh).

Here are two solutions I can think of to implement calling a possibly remote process:

1. using `shell-command`: this has the advantage that it is fast (meets criterion b), but one needs to pass a full shell command (fails for criterion a).
2. using `start-file-process` as recommended by the [TRAMP documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Remote-processes): this is nice in terms of arguments handling (criterion a), but a new SSH connection seems to be called for each process, which dramatically slows things down in remote configurations (criterion b).

**NB:** these solutions also differ in that (1) is synchronous whereas (2) is asynchronous, but I don't mention it because (a)synchronicity doesn't matter for my application.

It looks like option (2) is slow because it spawns a new ssh process, whereas option (1) reuses an already existing one. **Is there any high-level function allowing to call a possibly remote process, while still being efficient by reusing an existing connection if possible?**

---

Below is the code I used to benchmark both solutions:

```
(let ((test/remote-buffer (find-file "/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/LOGIN/"))
      (test/output-buffer (get-buffer-create "*hostname*")))
  (with-current-buffer test/output-buffer
    (erase-buffer))

  (with-current-buffer test/remote-buffer
    (setq test/begin (current-time))
    (shell-command "hostname" test/output-buffer)
    (message "1-Elapsed: %f" (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) test/begin))))

  (with-current-buffer test/remote-buffer
    (setq test/begin (current-time))
    (set-process-sentinel
     (start-file-process "hostname" test/output-buffer "hostname")
     (lambda (p e)
       (message "2-Elapsed: %f" (float-time (time-subtract (current-time) test/begin)))))))
```

yielding output:

```
1-Elapsed: 0.010178
Tramp: Opening connection for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx using scp...
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh -q   -o ControlPath=/tmp/tramp.12155IuC.%r@%h:%p -o ControlMaster=auto -e none xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...done
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
Tramp: Opening connection for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx using scp...done
2-Elapsed: 1.116449
```

In the case of local processes, both implementations take a similar elapsed time, which is negligible (and often faster for solution 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about writing a "safe" version of `shell-command` that would properly escape arguments using `shell-quote-argument` ?

For example:

```
(defun safe-shell-command (args &optional output-buffer error-buffer)
  (apply 'shell-command (mapconcat 'shell-quote-argument args " ")
         output-buffer error-buffer nil))
```

(the same would easily apply to `async-shell-command`)

Obviously it has the same performance characteristics as `shell-command`

The manual has a section on [shell arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Shell-Arguments.html). It also mentions `combine-and-quote-strings`, which might be useful depending on the case: it produces "less quoted" arguments, for example `$` characters are left alone.

Comment: Thanks, this does the job nicely and simply. I have to admit I'm still a bit disappointed though: I feel like quoting and concatenating arguments into a string which will then be parsed by the shell is an unnecessary burden...